# Python wordcloud installing was stuck in decode error

Tags: python, pip, word-cloud

I used pip install wordcloud in cmd then I was stuck in decode error, here is the error info:

```
Collecting wordcloud
Using cached wordcloud-1.3.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pillow->wordcloud)
Installing collected packages: wordcloud
  Running setup.py install for wordcloud ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 55: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 55: invalid start byte
```

Problem seems caused by decode, please help me figure this out, very thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open file in

```
C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py
```

Change 'utf_8' to 'cp936' and save, then use pip install again.